# Get type name as string in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How can I get the type name of a supplied type as string with C++ using Visual Studio 2010?

Example:

```
class MyClass { ... };

std::string typestr;
typestr = typeof( MyClass );

//typestr should hold "MyClass" now
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typeid(type).name();
//Or
typeid(expression).name();
```

Will return type name. This feature is "implementation defined" and standard doesn't saying what exacly name function must return, however in VC++ it is returning what you need (note, that **in g++ name function have different behavior**).

For more information see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)  and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx) links.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a macro like @badgerr says, if you can deduce it at compile-time. If you need it at runtime, then you need to enable RTTI (run-time type information) and use the `typeid` operator, which returns a `const type_info&` object, which has a `name` method. You can use it either with an expression or with a typename.

```
class myClass{
    // ...
};

int main(void){
    myClass myObject;
    cout << "typeid(myObject).name() = " << typeid(myObject).name() << endl;
    if (typeid(myObject) == typeid(myClass) {
        cout << "It's the same type as myClass" << endl;
    }   
}
```

[More on `typeid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[typeid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) may be what you need.

Or you could use some ugly define hacks:

```
//# is the Stringizing operator
#define typeof(X) #X
```

See here for docs/warnings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: The preprocessor solution will of course only work compile-time. A generic runtime-solution is impossible since C++ doesn't have reflection (you'd need a managed language like Java or C# for that).